# How to do linear interpolation?

Tags: interpolation

Here in my book they have shown interpolation using parametric equation of line but I am unable to figure out how do they found out t=|y1-ys|/y1-y2 , t=|AD|/|AB| , t=|CE|/CB ,t=|EP|/|DE| here is the  pic [image]

[image]

Comment: I prefer to think that linear interpolation is a weighted average with linked weights so that  $p_i = t p_1 + (1 - t) p_2$ because this is easier in vector form and also motivated by vector drawings. Obviously its the same thing but expressed differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is linear interpolation it boils down to solving a linear equation

$y = a + b t$

You can substitute the following $y = y_s$, $a = y_1$(intercept) and $b = y_2 - y_1$ (slope) to get the following

$$y_s = y_1 + t(y_2 - y_1)$$
$$y_s - y_1 = t(y_2 - y_1)$$
$$\frac{y_s - y_1}{y_2 - y_1} = t$$

The same thing happens for points where you can write

$$D = A + (B-A)t$$

$$ (D-A) = (B-A)\cdot t$$
$$ (D-A)^2 = ((B-A)\cdot t)^2$$
$$ \sqrt{(D-A)^2} = \sqrt{((B-A)\cdot t)^2}$$
$$ \sqrt{(D-A)^2} = \sqrt{(B-A)^2 \cdot t^2}$$
$$ \sqrt{(D-A)^2} = \sqrt{(B-A)^2} \cdot\sqrt{ t^2}$$
$$ |D-A| = |B-A| \cdot t$$
$$ t = \frac{|D-A|}{|B-A|}$$

Comment: But how could the slope be y2- y1 slope is : change in y over change in x i.e  ∆y/∆x

Comment: actually the slope in this case is ∆y/∆t

Answer (score -1):

I<sub>4</sub>=I<sub>1</sub>  ( 1-t ) + t.I<sub>2</sub>  ; from parametric equation of line

I4=I1 - I1.t + t. I2

I4=I1+ t (I2-I1)
Let's take line AB apart from triangle

[image]
below in the equation I multiply t<sup>2</sup> to numerator an denominator